# How to compare Clob column for multiple values?

Tags: oracle, clob

Can anyone tell me how to compare column which has clob datatype in oracle for multiple values?

```
For one value we are comparing like
dbms_lob.compare(attr_value,'A')=0
```

Similarly if I want to know whether attr_value is in ('A','B','C','D'). I tried this:

```
dbms_lob.compare(attr_value,'A')=0 or  dbms_lob.compare(attr_value,'B')=0 or ...
```

This is not giving me proper result. Is there any other way?

Comment: if you look the documentation:

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you don't really want to compare CLOBS of massive size with a bunch of other massive CLOBS, the fastest way would be to just compare a Substring of the CLOB:

```
WHERE DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( attr_value, 4000, 1 ) IN ('A','B','C')
```

Here 4000 can be replaced by the maximum length of all you comparison values.

If you really want to compare massive CLOBS I don't think a select is the right approach, you 
should probably rework your application logic...

Comment: I think you meant DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( attr_value, 4000, 1 )

Comment: @Multisync you are right... confusing syntax... sometimes offset first, sometimes length first

Answer (score 0):

OR should work fine. Also you may try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_tab WHERE CAST(s as VARCHAR2(2)) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

but I'm not sure about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_LOB.COMPARE does an exact comparison between two LOB objects. The documentation says:

> COMPARE returns zero if the data exactly matches over the range
>   specified by the offset and amount parameters. Otherwise, a nonzero
>   INTEGER is returned.

On Oracle 11g, you could use REGEXP_INSTR function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INTR(attr_value,'A|B|C|D|E') from dual;
```

I hope it helps.